# How to deduct 100 to zero using nested for loop c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested

Basically my program is to deduct 100 by two person until it is reach zero. I'm using nested for loop. 1 loop for each person as the person need to enter an integer. That integer will be deducted with 100.

But the main problem is I can't repeat the 1st loop without losing current value of 100. I'm a beginner.

```
for( int x = 1; x<=100;)
{
  cout <<"\n\n"<< nP1 <<" how many of the remaining " << chips<<" chip(s) would you like?"<<endl;
  cin >> P1c;
  result = chips-P1c;
  cout <<result;

    for( int y = 1; y <=100;)
    {
    cout <<"\n\n"<< nP2 <<" how many of the remaining " << result<<" chip(s) would you like?"<<endl;
    cin >> P2c;
    result = result-P2c;
    cout <<result;
    break;
    }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUGui.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. You have a value of 100 and you ask 2 users to substract a number from this value one after the other, is that it?

Comment: @MrPromethee yup exactly.

Comment: You have to do both players in the same loop.

Comment: @Zaidi Then I don't understand the need for nested loops, you could use a single loop in which you ask both users.

Answer (score 0):

For-loops aren't suited for this – "repeat until something is zero", as you're describing the problem, is very different from "repeat one hundred times", as you tried to solve it.

If you were playing this in real life, you would probably do something like this:

```
while there are any chips left
   let person 1 pick some chips
   if there are still any chips left
       let person 2 pick some chips
```

Translating to code left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to simulate is a group of people eating out of one bag of chips. Your problem with your current code is 2-fold. y and x never decrement, but you shouldn't even be using x and y as your counters. You should be using the number of chips in the bag as your counter, and decrement it after each person eats.

While loops are better suited to this problem. But if you must use for loops...

```
int num_people = 2;
int people[num_people];
int tmp;

// Begin eating
for (int chips = 100; chips > 0;)
{
    // Rotate through group of people
    for (int i = 0; i < num_people; i++)
    {
        printf("Person %d take chips >\n", i);
        cin >> tmp;

        // No person can take more than the remaining chips
        tmp = max(tmp, chips);

        // Increment chip eating total for each person
        people[i] += tmp;
        chips -= tmp;

        // Break the rotation if there are no more chips to eat
        if (chips <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Lets see who ate how many for fun
for (int i = 0; i < num_people; i++)
{
    printf("Person %d had %d chips\n", i, people[i]);
}

return 0;
```

Comment: OP did say "must for loop". As you said a while loop would be much better

Comment: To whoever voted me down, maybe his assignment requires for loops. His question was how to do his task using for loops.